# Subtract one day using datetime is changing the month

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am using the datetime.datetime.timedelta to subtract a day from today. When I run the code it is changing the Month part of the Datetime class property for some reason. Please help explain.

```
days_to_subtract = 1
date = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_subtract))
```

I expect the result for it to be 2/10/2019, but the output gives 10/02/2019.

Comment: it's returning `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: thanks, I looked at the object and thought it was changing the month not the day, but you are right it just swapped the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
days_to_subtract = 1
date = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_subtract))

print (date)
#output
2019-02-10 13:02:07.645241

print (date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
#output
02/10/2019
```